# Importing Shapefile into PostGIS and EPSG of created table is different from Shapefile?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr, epsg

I'm trying to import a Shapefile into PostGIS using the ogr2ogr, but it seems that the OGR is not automatically getting the EPSG from Shapefile.

My Shapefile has EPSG 4618, but the table created by ogr2ogr has EPSG 900914.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=x dbname=x user=x password=x" points.shp -nln points -skipfailures -lco FID=id -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on? Because the files (* .dbf, * .shx and so on) are in the same folder of the * .shp file.

I send below two print screens: one from shapefile and the other from PostGIS, showing the EPSG of each one, that are different, but they should be equal.

Shapefile:
[image]

PostGIS:
[image]

The content of .prj file is:

```
GEOGCS["SAD69",DATUM["D_South_American_1969",SPHEROID["GRS_1967_Truncated",6378160,298.25]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

Comment: Maybe this will help (follow Elzouavo's post from Oct 25, 2012; 2:34am; let us know if it helps): http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Why-have-I-got-SRS-900914-in-my-PostGIS-table-after-ogr2ogr-alimentation-td5010455.html

Comment: Please add the contents of the .prj file into your question.

Comment: Thank you Andre, it seems the same error. Do you know how to delete the 900914 entry? When I searched by EPSG 4618, it was found in the spatial_ref_sys and when I searched by the EPSG 900914, it was not found in the spatial_ref_sys. 
user30184, I added the .prj in the question.